# Ext.Msg.confirm inside function return value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to create a function that returns a (boolean)result when the user clicks yes or no. I'm using a `Ext.Msg.confirm`. Below my function (testcase).

```
function returnAnswer() {

    Ext.Msg.confirm('HardCoded', 'Do you want hard-coded strings in your application?', 
    function(btn) {
        if (btn === 'yes') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

In the above function a "callback" function returns a result and not my actual function.
How can I get `returnAnswer` function return a result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`returnAnswer` should pass a callback:

```
function returnAnswer(callback) {
    Ext.Msg.confirm('HardCoded', 'Do you want hard-coded strings in your application?', 
    function(btn) {
       callback.call(this, btn === 'yes');
    });
}
```

Comment: Exactly, was 1 min too late.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.confirm()` it returns boolean value.